# Storing a Function

Tags: python

```
import sys
print("Hello I am FoodBot, welcome to Fire n' Fusion. Please choose your item in each category.")
print("When I ask for your choices enter the code of the menu item.")
menuname= str(input("What is the name you would like your order placed under:"))
questioninput= int(input("Would like to eat here or would you like your order to-go? Enter 1 for eating here and 2 if you would like your meal to-go:"))
if questioninput < 1 or questioninput > 2:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
print("Here are the appetizers...")
print("-------------------------------")
print("Honey Chilli Potatoes($3.20) - Use Code 1")
print("Paneer Lettuce Wraps($5.10) - Use Code 2")
print("Mini Chicken Tamales($3.55) - Use Code 3 ")
print("Fiery Chicken Meatballs($5.99) - Use Code 4")
print("Enter 5 for Nothing")
appetizerinput = int(input("Enter what you would like in APPETIZERS[Code = 1-5]: "))
if appetizerinput == 1:
    item_price_app = 3.20
elif appetizerinput == 2:
    item_price_app = 5.10
elif appetizerinput == 3:
    item_price_app = 3.55
elif appetizerinput == 4:
    item_price_app = 5.99
elif appetizerinput == 5:
    item_price_app = 0.00
elif appetizerinput < 1 or appetizerinput > 5:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
print("Here are the Entrees...")
print("-------------------------------")
print("Gobi Munchurian($7.21) - Use Code 6")
print("Grilled Veggie Skewers($5.33) - Use Code 7")
print("Paneer Kathi Rolls($7.79) - Use Code 8")
print("Lemon and Ginger Chicken($8.60) - Use Code 9")
print("Hot Chicken Lasagna($6.45) - Use Code 10")
print("Prisha's Favorite Chicken n'Cheese Enchiladas ($7.84) - Use Code 11")
print("Enter 12 for Nothing")
entreeinput = int(input("Enter what you would like in ENTREES [Code 6-12]:"))
if entreeinput == 6:
    item_price_ent = 7.21
elif entreeinput == 7:
    item_price_ent = 5.33
elif entreeinput == 8:
    item_price_ent = 7.79
elif entreeinput == 9:
    item_price_ent = 8.60
elif entreeinput == 10:
    item_price_ent = 6.45
elif entreeinput == 11:
    item_price_ent = 7.84
elif entreeinput == 12:
    item_price_ent = 0.00
elif entreeinput < 6 or entreeinput > 12:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
print("Here are the Choices for Bread and Rice...")
print("-------------------------------")
print("Cumin Rice($2.25) - Use Code 13")
print("Egg Friedrice($3.25) - Use Code 14")
print("Plain Kulcha($1.50) - Use Code 15")
print("AlooKulcha($2.25) - Use Code 16")
print("Enter 17 for Nothing")
breadandriceinput = int(input("Enter what you would like in BREAD AND RICE [Code 13-17]:"))
if breadandriceinput == 13:
    item_price_brice = 2.25
elif breadandriceinput == 14:
    item_price_brice = 3.25
elif breadandriceinput == 15:
    item_price_brice = 1.50
elif breadandriceinput == 16:
    item_price_brice = 2.25
elif breadandriceinput == 17:
    item_price_brice = 0.00
elif breadandriceinput < 13 or breadandriceinput > 17:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
print("Here are the Choices for Desserts...")
print("-------------------------------")
print("Arabic King-Sweets($3.99) - Use Code 18")
print("Coconut Fried IceCream($2.50) - Use Code 19")
print("Supreme Vanilla Fudge($3.75) - Use Code 20")
print("Enter 21 for Nothing")
dessertinput = int(input("Enter what you would like in DESSERTS [Code 18-21]:"))
if dessertinput == 18:
    item_price_des = 3.99
elif dessertinput == 19:
    item_price_des = 2.50
elif dessertinput == 20:
    item_price_des = 3.75
elif dessertinput == 21:
    item_price_des = 0.00
elif dessertinput < 18 or dessertinput > 21:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
print("Here are the Choices for Drinks...")
print("-------------------------------")
print("Chai($1.00) - Use Code 22")
print("Cookies n' Cream Milkshake($2.50) - Use Code 23")
print("Bottle of Water($1.25) - Use Code 24")
print("FountainDrink($1.50) - Use Code 25")
print("Enter 26 for Nothing")
drinkinput = int(input("Enter what you would like in DRINKS [Code 22-26]:"))
if drinkinput == 22:
    item_price_dri = 1.00
elif drinkinput == 23:
    item_price_dri = 2.50
elif drinkinput == 24:
    item_price_dri = 1.25
elif drinkinput == 25:
    item_price_dri = 1.50
elif drinkinput == 26:
    item_price_dri = 0.00
elif drinkinput < 22 or drinkinput > 26:
    sys.exit("Sorry there was an error in your input. Please retry!")
sauceinput = str(input("Would you like a sauce platter with your meal(enter Yes or No)FREE!:"))
def mybill():
    print("                          ")
    print("                          ")
    print("                          ")
    print("                          ")
    print("    -----Fire n' Fusion------")
    if questioninput == 1:
        print("Meal:EATING IN THE RESTARAUNT")
    elif questioninput == 2:
        print("Meal:TO-GO ORDER")
    if appetizerinput == 1:
        print("Honey Chilli Potatoes: " + "    $3.20")
    elif appetizerinput == 2:
        print("Paneer Lettuce Wraps: " + "     $5.10")
    elif appetizerinput == 3:
        print("Mini Chicken Tamales: " + "     $3.55")
    elif appetizerinput == 4:
        print("Fiery Chicken Meatballs: " + "  $5.99")
    if entreeinput == 6: 
        print("Gobi Munchurian: " + "          $7.21")
    elif entreeinput == 7:
        print("Grilled Veggie Skewers: " + "   $5.33")
    elif entreeinput == 8:
        print("Paneer Kathi Rolls: " + "       $7.79")
    elif entreeinput == 9:
        print("Lemon and Ginger Chicken: " + " $8.60")
    elif entreeinput == 10:
        print("Hot Chicken Lasagna: " + "      $6.45")
    elif entreeinput == 11:
        print("Prisha's Favorite Chicken n' Cheese Enchiladas:" + "$7.84")
    if breadandriceinput == 13:
        print("Cumin Rice: " + "               $2.25")
    elif breadandriceinput == 14:
        print("Egg Fried Rice: " + "           $3.25")
    elif breadandriceinput == 15:
        print("Plain Kulcha: " + "             $1.50")
    elif breadandriceinput == 16:
        print("Aloo Kulcha: " + "              $2.25")
    if dessertinput == 18:
        print("King-Sweets: " + "              $3.75")
    elif dessertinput == 19:
        print("Coconut Fried Ice Cream: " + "  $2.50")
    elif dessertinput == 20:
        print("Supreme Vanilla Fudge: " + "    $3.75")
    if drinkinput == 22:
        print("Chai: " + "                     $1.00")
    elif drinkinput == 23:
        print("Cookies n' Cream Milkshake:" + "$2.50")
    elif drinkinput == 24:
        print("Bottle of Water: " + "         $1.25")
    elif drinkinput == 25:
        print("Fountain Drink: " + "          $2.50")
    totalcost = round(item_price_app + item_price_ent + item_price_brice + item_price_des + item_price_dri, 2) 
    print("Order Name:" +                               menuname)
    print("   Total:"     +         str              (totalcost))
    taxresult = round(totalcost*0.0775, 2)
    print("   Tax:"        +        str              (taxresult))
    mysubtotal = round(totalcost+taxresult, 2)
    print("   Subtotal:"    +      str              (mysubtotal))
    print("-------HEAD TO THE CASHIER TO PAY-------")
    print("  --Thank you For Choosing Fire n' Fusion--")
    print("   *********ENJOY YOUR MEAL!*********"   )
mybill()
```

This above is my code. You will notice that I have a function called mybill in it. I need someone to explain to me how to store the output of the bill in a file so the restaurant manager can go back, use user input to enter a date, and see all the bills that were from that specific date he entered. I do not need my whole code to be stored, I only need the output of each of the times a bill is printed to be stored by the date it was printed. Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of code! Can you simplify it down to a much smaller example?

Comment: This is a bit broad, as there are many good ways to store data. You can use `json.dump`, or `pickle.dump`. You could use regular old `open(filename, "w")` and design your own file format specification. You could use of one of the many third party database libraries. Each of these has some benefit over the other, in terms of simplicity or efficiency or scalability or  portability, etc etc. So it's hard to say what you ought to be using. Maybe research each of these available possibilities, and see what you find comfortable.

Comment: @Kevin Ok thanks, can you go into depth about that?

Comment: @chrisz I am not quite sure how to do that.

Comment: Your function doesn't have a return. I would advise adding the information to a return statement and storing it how you'd like.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  It doesn't take all that code to illustrate the problem, and you've failed to do even basic research on how to open and write to a file -- many examples on line.

Comment: changed `print` statements to append to a list, then write the list to a file: https://repl.it/@downshift/AlienatedTrickyGeneric similar to how Maharshi did in below answer

Comment: @davedwards I get what you mean. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably many options to do this, depending on how fancy you want to be and how adept you are at programming.  A database would probably be ideal, but you could use a simple dictionary.

Using a dictionary with date keys:

```
sales = {date1: {sale1:[], sale2:[]..., date2: {sale1:[], sale2:[]...}
```

If you have a dictionary stored as a pickle, you could work this into your code (modifying as needed).

```
import pickle
import datetime as dt

# define today's date
heute = dt.date.today()

with open('data.p', 'rb') as fid:
    data = pickle.load(fid)

# when adding data to your dictionary
if heute not in data:
    data[heute] = {}

# add sale
item = 'soup'
cost = 5.60
quantity = 4

salenum = 'sale' + str(len(data[heute]) + 1)
data[heute][salenum] = {}
data[heute][salenum][item] = {}
data[heute][salenum][item]['cost'] = cost
data[heute][salenum][item]['quantity'] = quantity

# store data to pickle
with open('data.p', 'wb') as fid:
    pickle.dump(data, fid)
```

When you want to get sales for each day:

```
with open('data.p', 'rb') as fid:
    data = pickle.load(fid)

# specify date of interest
doi = dt.date(2017, 1, 1)

if doi not in data:
    print('No sales today!')
else:
    for sale in sorted(data[doi]):
        for item in data[doi][sale]:
            print(item + 'x' + data[doi][sale][item]['quantity'] + ' @ $' + data[doi][sale]['cost'] + ' each')
```

This is just a general outline of something you could do with a dictionary, and should be easily modifiable for your needs.

## NOTE

This code is not ready to run (don't copy/paste), it is just an example of one option that will work (tweaking required).

Answer (score 1):

You could use python's datetime package for the current date and time

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
```

See [here](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/06/how-to-get-current-date-and-time-in/) for additional information

And then use python's built in file management stuff to read/write to/from a csv file

```
receipt_file= open("Receipts.csv", 'a')
receipt_file.write(str(now.year) +',' + str(now.month) + ',' str(now.day) + ',' + str(total_cost))
receipt_file.close()
```

And when you read it back in to sort by user input, you could even split by year, month, and day

```
receipt_file= open("Receipts.csv", 'r')
for line in receipt_file.readlines():
    year = line.split(',')[0]
    month = line.split(',')[1]
    # And so on - maybe even add list of receipts found with given criteria?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a simple text file with append functionality and write all the strings one by one in bill and store that bill with some naming convention so that you can open that bill again with your code in future by passing that name string (i.e the bill date).
To write your output in code to bill text file you can do the following:

You have multiple print statements in a method. You can assign those to a string and print them in terminal as well copy them to your text file.

```
def mybill():   
    with open("bill.txt", "a") as mybillfile:
            # use following structure for every print statement
            str = "    -----Fire n' Fusion------"
            myfile.write(str)
            print(str)
```